# Helper library for distributed algorithms programming?

Tags: c++, algorithm, distributed-computing, distributed-algorithm

When you code a distributed algorithm, do you use any library to model abstract things like processor, register, message, link, etc.? Is there any library that does that?

I'm thinking about e.g. self-stabilizing algorithms, like self-stabilizing minimum spanning-tree algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [DVM system](http://www.keldysh.ru/dvm/) that can be used for implementing different distributed algorithms. It works on top of [MPI](http://www.mpi-forum.org/).

However it is more for matrix-oriented scientific algorithms where distribution is done in terms of data blocks. I had a brief experience using it - it's much more convenient than direct usage of MPI and allows for much more readable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find the distributed Apache projects to be helpful:

- [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/hdfs_design.html) provides distributed filesystems and processing
- [Apache Zookeeper](http://hadoop.apache.org/zookeeper/docs/current/zookeeperOver.html) is a coordination service, which might be right up your alley.  It can be used as a public-subscribe mechanism.

There's also the [Java Parallel Processing Framework](http://www.jppf.org/) which abstracts entire machines and their composition, allowing you to focus on the processing.

Depends on your needs.